# Keystone JS retrieve row ID in HTML table

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug, keystonejs

I'm having some trouble to update some info :

I have an array where each line is a form. Here what it looks like in jade :

```
each info in infos
    form(method="post")
        input(type='hidden', name='action', value='save')
        td
            input(value='#{info.name.full}' disabled).form-control
        td
            input(value='#{info.field}' disabled).form-control
        td
            input(value='#{info.field1}' disabled).form-control
        td
            input(value='#{info.field2}' disabled).form-control
        td
            input(value='#{info.field3}' disabled).form-control
        td
            input(value='#{info.field4}' disabled).form-control     
        td
            input(value='#{info.field5}' disabled).form-control
        td
            input(value='#{info.field6}' disabled).form-control
        td
            input(value='#{info.field7}' disabled).form-control
        td
            select(name='status').form-control
                option(value="")=(require)
                option(value="bla")="Bla"
                option(value="blabla")="Bla bla"
                option(value="blablabla")="Bla bla bla"
                option(value="blablablabla")="Bla bla bla bla"
        td
                button(type='submit').btn.btn-primary Save
```

And I'd like to be able to save each line but I can't retrieve the ID when clicking on "save".

My JavaScript looks like this :

```
view.on('post', { action: 'save' }, function (next) {

    var application = new Info.model();
    var updater = application.getUpdateHandler(req);

    updater.process(req.body, {
        flashErrors: true
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            locals.validationErrors = err.errors;
        } else {
            locals.updateSubmitted = true;
        }
        next();
    });

});
```

But I guess I don't understand how the updateHandler works.

Does anyone have an idea of how to save the row by retrieving the ID ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it, I added

```
input(type='hidden', name='id', value='#{info.id}')
```

Just after

```
input(type='hidden', name='action', value='save')
```

Then I had access to the data with :

```
console.log(req.body.id);
console.log(req.body.item1);
```

And I updated my table like that :

```
    Info.model.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, { $set: {field1: req.body.item1, field2: item2}}, 
            function(err, info) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            }
    });
```

Hope this will help some of you.